# Upper Bound Error in nloptr

Tags: c#, r, excel, nonlinear-optimization, r.net

I use `nloptr` to model a non linear optimization problem using `R.Net` . I pass initial values of the parameters to the Rscript where I define `lb` and `ub`to the variables.

`lb` for all the variables is 0 whereas `ub`is "1" for some & "Inf" for some variables.

When I run the model, I am continuously getting an error as

```
Additional information: Error in is.nloptr(ret) : at least one element in x0 > ub
```

Interestingly if I provide the same initial input data from EXCEL to "R.Script", it runs fine and I never get error about `x0>ub`. 
Any insights on how to debug this or know what might be wrong? I can'f fathom why it would work with excel but not with C#.

Some details are below:
Example:  Parameters are in the form of Matrix as below (called my.data.var)

[image]

The constraints are such that sum of the second col and third col should be **<=1** respectively. i.e,
[image]

The lb for all parameters is 0 and i define it as:

```
lb = vector("numeric",length= length(my.data.var))
```

ub as:

```
ub.matrix <- matrix(,nrow = 2, ncol=4)  
ub.matrix
for(rownum in 1:2)  
{
  ub.matrix[rownum,1] = Inf                     
  ub.matrix[rownum,4] = Inf    
  for(colnum in 2:3) 
  {
    ub.matrix[rownum,colnum] = 1              
  }
}
```

The constraint func is defined as:

```
constraint.func <- function(my.data.var)
{
  column = 1

  constr <- vector("numeric",length = 2)   
  my.data.var.mat <- matrix(my.data.var,nrow = 2,ncol = 4,byrow = TRUE)  


  for(index in 2:3)
  {
    sum.constraint = 0
    for(prodwells in 1:2)
    {
      sum.constraint <- sum.constraint + my.data.var.mat[prodwells,index]

    }
    constr[column] <- sum.constraint - 1
    column = column+1
  }
  return(constr)

}

result <- nloptr(my.data.var,eval_f = Error.func, lb=lb,
                 ub = ub,eval_g_ineq=constraint.func,
                 opts = opts)
```

When I run the script, I noticed that "sum" of the first col is >1 and hence the error!

Comment: can you make this reproducible?

Comment: You are basically posting _only_ an error message and asking us what went wrong.

Comment: Interesting problem! I'll be happy to look at it as soon as I can reproduce it :D

Comment: @renatovitolo : added code.

Comment: @42- : Added code.

Comment: @shayaa: added more information with code.

Comment: We are closer to reproducibility, but not quite there yet.
`my.data.matrix.prod`  and `my.data.matrix.inj` are defined as integers, but in fact they should be matrices: you call `ncol()` on them both to construct `ub` and within the constraint function. Also: do I see it correctly that `my.data.var <- matrix(c(30,25,0.3,0.5,0.2,0.6,30,60), nrow=2)`? Lastly: could you also please add the call (or sequence of commands) where you "run the model", resulting in the error in `is.nloptr(ret)`?

Comment: Good catch. I updated the code. It's actually ncol(my.data.matrix.prod) = 2 and ncol(my.data.matrix.inj) = 2.  Yes your understanding of my.data.var is correct! @renatovitolo

Comment: 1. I still do not see the call (or sequence of commands) where you "run the model", resulting in the error in `is.nloptr(ret)`; therefore, I cannot reproduce your problem.
2. `ncol(my.data.matrix.prod) = 2` is not correct; for the purposes of this example you probably intend to define an auxiliary variable `ncol.my.data.matrix.prod = 2` and substitute `ncol.my.data.matrix.prod` to all occurrences of `ncol(my.data.matrix.prod)` -- and the same for `ncol(my.data.matrix.inj)`  should this be correct, could you please update your code?

Comment: @renatovitolo : Modified sir. See the last section of the code. That's where I call the function.

Comment: The definition of `Error.func` is still missing: example is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the "Inf" limit solves my problem at hand.